# Android google repository - keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard

guys, I'm looking for the source of the official android keyboard code but whenever I find in the official repositories, it is always with missing classes. I wonder where I can find the source (which is open), this terclado to be able to create and modify it and that works in versions 2.2 to the last.

I want to create an application where I can customize the layout with specific colors, etc. audio inputs and the like.

They could help me? I know it's maybe my question is not appropriate but do not give negative to block my account.

I just want to know where I can get the full source google Keyboard customize for me, but whenever I think, is missing classes at SRC.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Repos you can use

[AnySoftKeyboard.git](https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard.git)

[LatinIME](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME)

A quick and concise google search is all you need to get what I just got. The first one is open source so it should be properly documented. The second one has a weird layout, but I don't use Google Source, so I wouldn't know how well it works/functions.